# Term used to describe scalar coupling over a single bond?

Tags: terminology, nmr-spectroscopy

I know that coupling on NMR over two bonds is referred to as geminal coupling and over three bonds is referred to as vicinal coupling. However is there a term for coupling over one bond (such as a carbon-13 bonded to a fluorine?

Comment: As far as I know it's usually called "one-bond coupling". Like DSVA I've never heard of any other special term. For example: http://u-of-o-nmr-facility.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/weak-one-bond-or-multiple-bond.html

Comment: FWIW: [geminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geminal) and [vicinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicinal_(chemistry)) are generic chemistry terms and not unique to NMR at all. The technically correct way to describe coupling is to use the _J_ descriptor; but common expressions include _directly bonded_ and especially _one-bond coupling_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never heard a special term but you can describe it as $^1 J$ or $^1 J_{CF}$ coupling using the systematic nomenclature.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the [IUPAC convention](http://old.iupac.org/reports/1997/6912harris/) for J specifies that the nucleus of higher mass should come first; hence this would be J(FC). Not sure that this convention is strictly adhered to in literature though